# RGB/VGA input on display without analog ports

Tags: display, hdmi, vga, cable

I've got a [Panasonic LCD display](http://shop.panasonic.com/shop/model/TC-L58E60) that has all digital or HDMI ports for video. In our conference room, I need to support VGA input for those connecting PC laptops that have no digital output. I've tried [these types of adapters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C0Y6BQG) that claim to do VGA-to-HDMI, to no avail - none of the ones I've tested work at all.

Anyone have any experience with converters that work in this situation? The display does have component inputs, so was debating a VGA-to-component cable, but not sure that'll be any more reliable.

Comment: In case the answer below is unclear, the product you linked is HDMI-to-VGA.  For VGA-to-HDMI, you need a more expensive converter.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, your display is a home product.  If you're buying a display for a conference room, you should be looking at commercial/business displays, which _always_ have a VGA input.

Comment: Thanks! True, I knew that about the display when we purchased it, but figured I could get a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a converter like [this one](http://www.monoprice.com/Product?c_id=101&cp_id=10114&cs_id=1011404&p_id=6191).

Most converters are HDMI to VGA that I have seen.  Most (reliable) VGA to HDMI converters are **powered**.  Try one of those and it will likely solve your issue.

Comment: Jason was right, your link was HDMI TO VGA.  Not what you need.

Comment: I'll look into one of those adapters. Now that I look at it, it's definitely the wrong type of converter (but I can probably find another place to use it). Thanks for the help!